# Анимация курсора при наведении на ссылку

Tags: html, css

Можно ли сделать плавную анимацию перехода из `cursor: url();` в `cursor: pointer;`, если да, то как?

Comment: Никак. Если только через JS, ну или говнокодить..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно спрятать курсор и подвигать с помощью js свои картиночки.
Но тут будет небольшой дилэй.

```js
onmousemove = e => {
  if(e.x < innerWidth/2) document.body.className = 'c1'
  else document.body.className = 'c2'
  c1.style.transform = `translate(${e.x}px, ${e.y}px)`
  c2.style.transform = `translate(${e.x}px, ${e.y}px)`
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: none;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, tomato 0%, tomato 50%, lightblue 50%, lightblue 100%);
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.c1 #c1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.c2 #c2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg id="c1" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width=25 height=25>
  <path d="M429.742,319.31L82.49,0l-0.231,471.744l105.375-100.826l61.89,141.083l96.559-42.358l-61.89-141.083L429.742,319.31z M306.563,454.222l-41.62,18.259l-67.066-152.879l-85.589,81.894l0.164-333.193l245.264,225.529l-118.219,7.512L306.563,454.222z"/>
</svg>

<svg id="c2" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width=25 height=25>
  <path d="m82.401 313.39c3.816 5.087 65.562 87.394 80.015 106.661-.037 22.01-.037 76.43-.037 77.026 0 8.284 6.716 15 15 15h180c8.284 0 15-6.716 15-15v-90.759l27.848-167.085c5.538-14.294 18.165-47.93 27.574-80.83 9.77-34.162 23.118-85.914-4.851-97.102-22.962-9.186-45.93 20.111-65.367 49.983-8.61 13.233-17.095 27.78-24.596 41.325-8.237-10.653-21.13-17.532-35.607-17.532-8.022 0-15.553 2.12-22.082 5.814-8.003-12.502-22.004-20.814-37.918-20.814-9.405 0-18.141 2.905-25.37 7.858-7.109-29.029-20.118-78.601-34.41-104.851-3.417-6.277-13.804-25.378-31.485-22.855-21.49 3.07-24.171 26.72-24.999 48.647-1.334 35.399 3.511 98.177 14.797 191.576-6.377-.244-12.592-.374-18.534-.374-37.994-.001-58.543 44.215-34.978 73.312zm327.342-220.146c.615 32.205-26.398 106.664-38.036 136.558-.374.961-.648 1.958-.818 2.976l-28.306 169.833c-.136.815-.204 1.64-.204 2.466v77h-150.003l.003-66.971c.01-3.254-.992-6.422-2.941-9.027-.048-.065-58.217-77.604-83.224-110.939-9.124-12.155-.197-25.063 11.166-25.063 35.083 0 87.421 5.1 119.446 14.023-11.818 3.046-30.91 6.999-61.719 11.721-8.188 1.255-13.809 8.911-12.554 17.1 1.255 8.188 8.905 13.807 17.1 12.554 51.946-7.963 92.26-15.42 100.719-31.897 21.091 18.024 56.557 5.19 61.511-93.728 13.331-26.199 45.769-87.117 67.86-106.606zm-112.364 71.833c8.271 0 15 6.729 15 15 0 25.717-3.357 69.141-15 87.636-5.631-8.945-15-36.492-15-87.636 0-8.271 6.729-15 15-15zm-60-15c8.271 0 15 6.729 15 15 0 33.563-4.393 67.691-11.115 89.133-2.644-.688-5.427-1.359-8.353-2.016-7.557-25.549-10.532-60.487-10.532-87.117 0-8.271 6.729-15 15-15zm-85.486-111.521c16.341 31.296 33.189 104.123 40.66 138.602.7 24.864 3.521 49.181 7.931 69.186-11.008-1.593-22.559-2.923-34.113-3.942-5.349-43.879-19.219-160.045-14.478-203.846z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: кстати стрелочка ещё и рисовать почему-то умеет...

Comment: спасибо, очень помогли=)